# Stroller for twins

Tags: twins, stroller

I was wondering if there are any strollers for twins that is separable available. It would be nice if we could just latch two strollers together when one person is pushing and separate them out into two when we need to.

Comment: Not an answer, but: bungee cords work very well, as long as the buggies are the same type :-)

Comment: This appears to be a shopping question, which is not going to work well here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ehow.co.uk/list_7453930_double-strollers-separate.html contains a list including:

- iCandy Apple / Pear
- Phil & Ted's Sport Buggy with Doubles Kit
- Uppa Baby Vista Stroller
- Baby Jogger City Select Stroller

You can also buy connectors to attach two single strollers:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Prince-Lionheart-6550-Stroller-Connectors/dp/B000056J23](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000056J23)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Munchkin-20065-Stroller-Links-Black/dp/B003XMWFAU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XMWFAU)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen one just once, but I don't recall the brand.
It doesn't seem to be as safe as the one I bought for my twins. At least, the mom that was pushing the latched strollers was having some trouble with so many wheels and uneven sidewalks.